# cpanel sent emails marked as spam

Tags: gmail, cpanel, spam-prevention, email-spam

my site use latest version of cpanel
but when i send email via cpanel email account to gmail,the gmail marked it as spam
where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if your mail server is not listed in spam databases.
Here is one: http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=173.194.32.21
When i opened spam message in gmail, then she said why it is in spam ...

Answer (score 2):

This can occur for many causes,

1. The first thing that causes many email services mark a message as SPAM is your IP address, maybe your IP address is listed as SPAM generator - But I think it's not very important for GMail.
2. You should set your Reverse DNS record because It's important too.
3. Maybe you're sending email with bad protocol parameters - I think cpanel does It good, I'm not a cpanel experienced.
4. Removing SPAM mark from emails helps to GMail removes the sender from blacklists.
5. Google has very good documents about how to send emails to GMail to not marking as SPAM.